# Why MapFallbackToController is not working: HTTP 401 UNAUTHORIZED Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

**I finished my app and i want to publish it into web. 
Working on core 3.1.1 + angular2.
I created Fallback controller for routes.
It seems MapFallbackToController is not working. I don't have acceses to these files because i'm unauthorized, but why?**
When i do "dotnet run" my page is blank and in the console:
[image]

Everything worked perfect until i moved angular files(wwwroot) into API proj.

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using RecipesApp.API.Controllers.Models.Data;
using RecipesApp.API.Data;
using RecipesApp.API.Helpers;

namespace RecipesApp.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>( x=> x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => {
                opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });

            services.AddCors();
            services.Configure<CloudinarySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("CloudinarySettings"));
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(RecipesRepository).Assembly);
            services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRecipesRepository, RecipesRepository>();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                    .GetBytes(Configuration
                    .GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
            services.AddScoped<LogUserActivity>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else 
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => 
                {
                    builder.Run(async context => 
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        if (error != null)
                        {
                            context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();



            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My fallback class

```
    public class Fallback : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "index.html"), "text/HTML");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your angular js file?Does your Fallback controller need authentication?Did the Index action being hit?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your startup file, i think you have specified that before a request gets to a controller, an authorization is needed, hence the error. In your case, can you try putting the AllowAnonymous attribute in your Fallback file as this tells netcore to map back to the fallback controller in search for angular index.html file. So, something like this;

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class Fallback : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "index.html"), "text/HTML");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `startup.cs` file, inside your `Configure()` method, out the `app.UseStaticFiles()` after `app.UseRouting()`. That's all.

Comment: Their code already has both `UseRouting()` _and_ `UseStaticFiles()`, also in that order. Did you mean to say "comment out" instead of just "out"? Otherwise, it's not clear (to me) what this is suggesting.